# What "wd" is supposed to mean from the utility tool passwd?

Tags: passwd

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/passwd.1.html

What "wd" is supposed to mean in the name of the utility tool passwd?

pass is for password - what about wd ?

Comment: He thought `wd` is an abbreviation for something else. In the same vein as many people see `srv` as an abbreviation for *server*, but `/srv` as a Linux folder actually refers to *service* or *to serve*. The questions is not fit for serverfault, but you don't have to be rude about his question.

Comment: @TomTom [unix.se] accepts history questions like this.

Comment: Didn't know about https://unix.stackexchange.com/. Thank you, Michael!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> pass is for password - what about wd ?

`passwd` is short for password. Fewer letters, less typing, more efficiency.

From wikipedia:

> **The file's name originates from one of its initial functions as it
> contained the data used to verify passwords of user accounts**. However,
> on modern Unix systems the security-sensitive password information is
> instead often stored in a different file using shadow passwords, or
> other database implementations.

Reference:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passwd#Password_file

Answer (score 1):

This can be even easier answered

Passwd is short of 2 words (logically meant), the first is pass which is clear and the second is the standard short for word also know as wd therefore it is also a known shortcut for pwd or Passwd in the IT-Based slang or full word password ;)

However, logically it is meant to pass with a word somewhat/somewhere ;) aka code word

Hope it's even clearly even also the other answered the question already